# Python: os.walk() in recursive function

Tags: python

I'm trying to use os.walk() in a recursive function to go through a whole directory recursively and rename files (just capitalising names of all files at a given path) . My (simple) code is here:

```
def recursiveRename(path):
    """ This uses the os.walk function to walk through a directory """
    rename(path)
    for root, sub, files in os.walk(path):
        i = 0
        print (sub)
        while(i < len(sub)):
            print (os.path.join(path, sub[i]))
            recursiveRename(os.path.join(path, sub[i]))
            i+=1
```

Which outputs this:

```
['one', 'two']
/Users/name/Desktop/test/one
['four', 'three']
/Users/name/Desktop/test/one/four
[]
/Users/name/Desktop/test/one/three
[]
[]
[]
/Users/name/Desktop/test/two
[]
['four', 'three']
/Users/name/Desktop/test/four
```

This renames all the files fine, but the last directory it tries doesn't exist (there are no subfolders in /test/two). I could just catch the error, but I feel my logic is a bit wrong and I'd rather figure that out.

Answer (score 3):

`os.walk()` **already** recurses through your directories, you don't need to recurse *again*.

Move `rename(path)` into your loop instead:

```
for root, sub, files in os.walk(path):
    rename(root)
```